# Linq query returns sql and not data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure what the problem is but I cant seem to get my program to display the correct information. The requirements for my application are to take a pdf and populate the form fields with information from a database. The problem is that it does not return the information from the database and instead returns  the sql generated from entity framework.

```
(text) SELECT 
[Extent1].[Applicant_ID] AS [Applicant_ID] 
FROM [dbo].[W4] AS [Extent1]
```

This is what is displayed in the pdf textbox.

This is my query

```
public class Query
{
    ApplicatoinContext context = new ApplicatoinContext();
    public List<W4> GetId()
    {
        return (from p in context.w4
                select new W4 { Applicant_ID = p.Applicant_ID }).ToList();

    }
}
```

My controller

```
 public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    // GET: Application
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

         string template = @"c:\users\carisch\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Idea\Idea\fw4.pdf";
        string newFile = @"c:\users\carisch\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Idea\Idea\Newfw4.pdf";

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(template);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));

        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

        Query num = new Query();

        var query = num.GetId();


        fields.SetField("f1_15_0_", query.ToString());

        stamper.FormFlattening = false;
        stamper.Close();

        return File(@"c:\users\carisch\documents\visual studio     2013\Projects\Idea\Idea\Newfw4.pdf", "application/pdf");   
    }


}
```

I'm pretty new to programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.